# Set metadata for all objects in a bucket in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, storage, bucket

In order to use GCP CDN, I need to set metadata (cache-control) for all the objects in a bucket. Do we have a command to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/) and `gsutil setmeta`:

1) Open [Cloud Shell](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard?cloudshell=true&_ga=2.36109408.-1996430322.1526587162) in Cloud Console.

2) If you want to set cache-control to "public" then execute in Cloud Shell: `gsutil setmeta -h "Cache-Control:public" gs://<YOUR-BUCKET-NAME>/*.*`

Just use the correct bucket name where you want to apply the update.
The setmeta documentation is [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/setmeta). You can change the right file extension (eg. ".html") based on the files type you want to update.

Comment: If you want "all the objects in a bucket" the path should be `gs://<YOUR-BUCKET-NAME>/**`, as per https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WildcardNames

Comment: And if you have a lot of files you may want to use the `-m` flag to run these in parallel, e.g. `gsutil -m setmeta -h ...`

Comment: I had to also use `-r` to ensure it works recursively.

Comment: An attempt to set the cache control setting for all the files in a particular folder with `gsutil setmeta -h "Cache-Control:private,max-age=0,no-store" gs://apparchlite.appspot.com/research_papers/Limestone Uplands/*.* ` returned the following error `setmeta" command does not support "file://" URLs. Did you mean to use a gs:// URL?` Any idea what that's all about?

Comment: Ah - `gsutil setmeta -r -h "Cache-Control:private,max-age=0,no-store" gs://apparchlite.appspot.com` applied  Cache-Control to the entire folder hierarchy - incuding Limestone Uplands. Thanks, kacase